# How to format the entries in Gtk.Entry

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

For example, the telephone format is `+999 99 9999-9999`. That is, the `GtkEntry` automatically add the characters (+,[space] and -) as the user types.

Comment: You could try having a [validator](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/libgtk2.0-doc/faq/x833.html). This old (2006) [discussion](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq14.022.htp&req=show) can also be useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. How to make an entry validator?

In order to do an entry validator in gtk, you need to connect the `insert_text` signal to a validation method. It goes like so:

```
class EntryWithValidation(Gtk.Entry):
    """A Gtk.Entry with validation code"""

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Entry.__init__(self)
        self.connect("insert_text", self.entryInsert)

    def entryInsert(self, entry, text, length, position):
        # Called when the user inserts some text, by typing or pasting.

        # The `position` argument is not working as expected in Python
        pos = entry.get_position() 

        # Your validation code goes here, outputs are new_text and new_position (cursor)

        if new_text:
            # Set the new text (and block the handler to avoid recursion).
            entry.handler_block_by_func(self.entryInsert)
            entry.set_text(new_text)
            entry.handler_unblock_by_func(self.entryInsert)

            # Can't modify the cursor position from within this handler,
            # so we add it to be done at the end of the main loop:
            GObject.idle_add(entry.set_position, new_pos)

        # We handled the signal so stop it from being processed further.
        entry.stop_emission("insert_text")
```

This code will generate a warning: `Warning: g_value_get_int: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_INT (value)' failed Gtk.main()` because of the incapacity of handling return arguments in the Python bindings of Gtk signals. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815694/gtk-3-position-attribute-on-insert-text-signal-from-gtk-entry-is-always-0) gives details about the bug. As suggested in the accepted answer, you can override the default signal handler like so:

```
class EntryWithValidation(Gtk.Entry, Gtk.Editable):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyEntry, self).__init__()

    def do_insert_text(self, new_text, length, position):

        # Your validation code goes here, outputs are new_text and new_position (cursor)

        if new_text:
            self.set_text(new_text)
            return new_position
        else:
            return position
```

### 2.The validation code

You now need to write the validation code. It is a bit fiddly since we need to place the cursor at the end of the inserted text but we may have added some extra characters while formatting.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

class TelNumberEntry(Gtk.Entry):
    """A Gtk.Entry field for phone numbers"""

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Entry.__init__(self)
        self.connect("insert_text", self.entryInsert)

    def entryInsert(self, entry, text, length, position):

        pos = entry.get_position() 
        old_text = entry.get_text()

        # Format entry text

        # First we filter digits in insertion text
        ins_dig = ''.join([c for c in text if c.isdigit()]) 
        # Second we insert digits at pos, truncate extra-digits
        new_text = ''.join([old_text[:pos], ins_dig, old_text[pos:]])[:17] 
        # Third we filter digits in `new_text`, fill the rest with underscores
        new_dig = ''.join([c for c in new_text if c.isdigit()]).ljust(13, '_')
        # We are ready to format 
        new_text = '+{0} {1} {2}-{3}'.format(new_dig[:3], new_dig[3:5], 
                                               new_dig[5:9], new_dig[9:13]).split('_')[0] 

        # Find the new cursor position

        # We get the number of inserted digits
        n_dig_ins = len(ins_dig) 
        # We get the number of digits before
        n_dig_before = len([c for c in old_text[:pos] if c.isdigit()])
        # We get the unadjusted cursor position
        new_pos = pos + n_dig_ins

        # If there was no text in the entry, we added a '+' sign, therefore move cursor
        new_pos += 1 if not old_text else 0 
        # Spacers are before digits 4, 6 and 10
        for i in [4, 6, 10]:
            # Is there spacers in the inserted text?
            if n_dig_before < i <= n_dig_before + n_dig_ins: 
                # If so move cursor
                new_pos += 1

        if new_text:
            entry.handler_block_by_func(self.entryInsert)
            entry.set_text(new_text)
            entry.handler_unblock_by_func(self.entryInsert)

            GObject.idle_add(entry.set_position, new_pos)

        entry.stop_emission("insert_text")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    entry = TelNumberEntry()
    window.add(entry)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Very good, your example works.
But I'm getting the warning: `gtkentry_with_formation.py:62: Warning: g_value_get_int: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_INT (value)' failed Gtk.main()`

Comment: Glad it works. The warning is due to a bug in handling the position argument in Python. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815694/gtk-3-position-attribute-on-insert-text-signal-from-gtk-entry-is-always-0

Comment: sorry to go back to that question.
Why do you make double inheritance with `Gtk.Entry` and `Gtk.Editable`, since `Gtk.Entry` inherits from `Gtk.Editable`?

Comment: This is to avoid overriding gtk.Editable implementation. See the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815694/gtk-3-position-attribute-on-insert-text-signal-from-gtk-entry-is-always-0, the note at the bottom explains this in more detail.