# GTK3 subclassing Gtk.Entry with `do_changed()` method

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

Can somebody explain this behaviour when subclassing `Gtk.Entry` with a `do_changed()` method:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyEntry(Gtk.Entry):
    def do_show(self):
        print('`{0._name}` show'.format(self))

    def do_changed(self):
        print('`{0._name}` changed, text is now {0.props.text!r}'.format(self))

    def do_activate(self):
        print('`{0._name}` activate'.format(self))

    def do_destroy(self):
        print('`{0._name}` destroy'.format(self))

gtk_entry = Gtk.Entry()
gtk_entry._name = 'gtk_entry'

my_entry = MyEntry()
my_entry._name = 'my_entry'

# Statement:                     # Output:
gtk_entry.show()                 #
my_entry.show()                  # `my_entry` show
                                 #
gtk_entry.props.text = 'Apples'  # `gtk_entry` changed, text is now 'Apples'
my_entry.props.text = 'Oranges'  # `my_entry` changed, text is now 'Oranges'
                                 #
gtk_entry.activate()             #
my_entry.activate()              # `my_entry` activate
                                 #
gtk_entry.destroy()              #
my_entry.destroy()               # `my_entry` destroy
```

Specifically, I don't understand why `gtk_entry.props.text = 'Apples'` would invoke `MyEntry.do_changed()`

---

[This answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38831655/8944057) says that "You have to inherit from Gtk.Editable in addition to Gtk.Entry" otherwise "you are overriding the base implementation provided by Gtk.Editable", but does anyone have a more in-depth explanation?